# Фоновое добавление в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть форма с полем для текста и инпутом:

```
<form action="?????" method="POST">
<textarea>Заметка</textarea>
<input class="inp1" type="button" name="sen_report" value="Добавить заметку">
</form>
```

мне надо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопки данные сразу же летели в MySQL, но как это сделать? если указать в action файл обработки, то пользователя перекинет сначала не него, даже если там сделать переадресацию header'ом

Comment: Вам нужно использовать [ajax](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax)

Comment: в action можно обработчиком указать саму страницу

Comment: ну да, но этот же файл является обработчиом другой страницы, как дать понять, как имено скрипт нужно выполнять? можно ли в экшн указать функцию и в этом же файле написать функцию на добавление в mysql из поля текстового записи?

Comment: жаль я не уменю в аякс, а средствами пхп никак?

Comment: не путайте front-end с back-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключайте [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) библиотеку и присваиваете форме уникальный идентификатор

```
<form id="note" action="" method="POST">
  <textarea name="note">Заметка тест</textarea>
  <input class="inp1" type="submit" name="sen_report" value="Добавить заметку">
</form>
```

И отправляете Ajax запрос при отправке формы

```
$(function() {
   $('#note').submit(function() {
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).find('textarea,input').serialize(), function(result) { alert('success'); });
      return false;
   });
});
```

Демо: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/greVYL

Comment: Поправил демо, вывел результат выполнения ajax запроса в `div.result`

Answer (score 3):

Рассмотрите возможность использования `$_POST` в рамках Вашего сценария, или же, пишите на AJAX в отдельном сценарии, что в любом случае будет лучше. PHP-решение примерно будет выглядеть так:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sen_report']) && !empty($_POST['sign'])) {
  # выполнить MySQL запрос по нажатию кнопки
}
else {?>
    <form method="POST">
        <textarea name="sign">Заметка</textarea>
        <input class="inp1" type="submit" name="sen_report" value="Добавить заметку">
    </form><?
}
?>
```

Comment: В чем смысл выносить в отдельную функцию html код формы?

Comment: Согласен. Вывел код в условие. Указал имя для textarea, чтобы содержимое поля передавалось в POST.

Comment: Окей, в чем смысл использовать `echo` когда можно после else закрыть `?>`, вставить фрагмент html кода и после открыть `<?php`

Comment: Можно. Но если этот код используется не в .htm* файле, то нельзя.

Comment: Кто вам такое сказал? PHP прекрасно работает в паре с html.

Comment: Файл с расширением `.php` может содержать html код. Пример: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ab99e45db6959d6c07651a8a002888299b0ba07

Comment: И еще:) Вы проверяете наличие параметра `sen_report` в POST запросе, однако нас интересует `sign` - сама заметка.

Comment: Насчет использования html-кода - ошибся, спасибо за замечание. Автора интересует "по нажатию кнопки", условие составлено так, как он ставил вопрос. Но с точки зрения логики - да, нужно и текст заметки проверить на то, есть ли он вообще.